# Group By and convert into a new entity on c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of entities like this

```
    public class Entity 
    {       
        string key { get; set; } 
        string code { get; set; } 
        string value { get; set; }
    }
```

and i want to group by key, cause there are some entities with the same key, and convert the group into a entity like this:

```
    public class Entity 
    {
        string key { get; set; }
        List<string> code { get; set; }
        List<string> value { get; set; }
    }
```

Key is not unique and one key can contains diferent codes and values, for example:

```
Key -> FOO
  Code ->  EN, Value -> Fom
  Code ->  ES, Value -> Fol
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Try linq group by: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results

Comment: Hi. If the answer below solved your problem please consider marking it as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. To access the properties from other classes, they will need to be marked as public. Also, public properties in C# conventionally have names in Pascal case. After using the `GroupBy()`, you can use `SelectMany()` to get all the Codes and Values. At the end, you can use `Select()` to create a new object to hold the result. I renamed one of the entity classes so that they could both be in the same namespace but you can have them with the same name if they are in different namespaces.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = new List<Entity>()
        {
            new Entity(){Key="one", Code="one", Value="1"},
            new Entity(){Key="one", Code="two", Value="2"},
            new Entity(){Key="two", Code="three", Value="3"},
            new Entity(){Key="two", Code="four", Value="4"},
        };

        var result = input
            .GroupBy(g => g.Key)
            .Select(g => new EntityResult() 
            { 
                Key = g.Key, 
                Code = g.Select(e => e.Code).ToList(), 
                Value = g.Select(e => e.Value).ToList(), 
            })
            .ToList();
    }
}

public class Entity
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class EntityResult
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<string> Code { get; set; }
    public List<string> Value { get; set; }
}
```

You could remove the calls to `ToList()` inside the `Select()` by changing the types of the properties in the EntityResult class from `List<string>` to `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: You can also use the `g.Key` instead of g.First().Key

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't know that. You learn something every day. I've updated the answer.